# Borrar registros de base de datos con tkinter python

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

Estoy creando este programa que tiene una funcion llamada **"eliminar_pais"** la cual como su nombre indica deberia eliminar un pais del registro de la base de datos segun el id que pongas en el entry. Al intentar eliminar un registro me da un error que no entiendo, me preguntaba si me podian ayudar a solucionar este problema, ya lei el codigo varias veces e intente varias soluciones sin lograr resultados, gracias de antemano.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import mysql.connector

root = tk.Tk()

# frames
fframe = tk.Frame(root)
fframe.pack()

# conexion bbdd

cnn = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", 
passwd = "password", database = "bbddejercicio")

##############ELIMINAR PAIS##############

try:
    def eliminar_pais():
        cur = cnn.cursor()
        sql = f'''DELETE FROM countries WHERE id = {entry_eliminar}'''
        cur.execute(sql)
        n = cur.rowcount
        cnn.commit()
        cur.close()

        messagebox.showinfo("BBDD", "Se han eliminado " + n + " paises")

except:
    messagebox.showerror("BBDD", "La id del pais que desea eliminar no existe")

# labels
label_eliminar = tk.Label(fframe, text = "Eliminar pais:")
label_eliminar.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = "w", padx = (20, 0))

label_eliminado = tk.Label(fframe, text = "ID del pais a eliminar")
label_eliminado.grid(row = 7, column = 3, sticky = "w")

# entry
entry_eliminar = tk.Entry(fframe)
entry_eliminar.grid(row = 7, column = 2)
entry_eliminar = tk.IntVar()

# button
button_eliminar = tk.Button(fframe, text = "Eliminar", command = eliminar_pais)
button_eliminar.grid(row = 8, column = 2, ipadx = 35, pady = (0, 20))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Comparte el error puede ser de ayuda.

Comment: in cmd_query       
    raise errors.get_mysql_exception(exc.errno, msg=exc.msg,
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'PY_VAR0' in 'where clause'

Comment: veo que en esta linea `sql = f'''DELETE FROM countries WHERE id = {entry_eliminar}'''` le estas pasando `entry_eliminar`, cuando deberías primero obtener el valor del `Entry` con su método `get()` ,algo así `entry_eliminar.get()`

Comment: @Boolean ahi estaaaa se me hacia que me estaba faltando un get por algun lado pero no sabia donde jajajaja. Muchas gracias boolean, me solucionaste los dos problemas que plantie en esta pagina. Ahora solo me queda desarrolar una funcion para insertar un pais y otro para modificar, vamos a ver si no me dan error